# Small java WebSocket Client, which supports subprotocol?

Tags: java, websocket, client

I have a WebSocket server in C (using libwebsockets) which differentiates between a few subprotocols. I now need a Java Client which is able to use different subprotocols. I tried TooTallNates Java-Websocket, but i think it dosent support different protocol types. Also i tired jetty but i cant make it work properly also it look a bit to complex for my task. i just want the possiblity to read and write messages using websocket and i dont need all those fancy extra features. Which libraries would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to create a basic Server, you can use the ServerSocket already in java, which is pretty easy. I am currently working on a sort of groupchat in a command-prompt and I've been using this method. My first answer, so feel free to ask back. (Or give feedback)

Comment: can I use different subprotocols in a client using Java Socket ?

Comment: Its very basic, you can create different Threads for the different tasks if you want to though.